# teleporting a game object to a position if a variable is a certan value

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to make a game object change its position if a variable is equal to:

```
void awake()
{
    if(GameControllerScript.CardNumber == 1)
    {       
        transform.position = new Vector3(8f, 6.89f, 9f);
    }
    sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

}
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what is wrong here?

Comment: When you say something is wrong what do you mean? Compilation error? Exception? ...

Comment: awake() needs to be Awake()

Comment: Has GameControllerScript.CardNumber been set to 1? Are you trying to set the position of the gameobject that this script resides on? Before your if statement, put a Debug.Log(GameControllerScript.CardNumber); and see if it is equal to 1.

Comment: GameControllerScript.CardNumber has been set to 1 and is set to 1 in the debug.log